# Unable to receive packets onto utun interface?

Tags: macos, network, vpn, swift, tunnel

I'm using the NetworkExtension framework to create a virtual `utun` interface. My application receives packets from a client and the application writes the packet into the `utun` interface.

Since I have enabled `ip forwarding` using `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1` on the system, the packet is sent to the correct interface `en0` and sent out through the wire.

When a response is sent back, it is received on the `en0` interface. However, I want to forward these packets to the `utun` interface so that my application can read the packets received. How can I achieve this?

Example:

1. VPN Application receives packet from client.
2. Application writes packet to `utun` interface with `source 100.64.0.77` and `destination 192.168.1.95`
3. OS networking stack sees that the packets destined for `192.168.x.x` are to go to interface `en0`
4. Packet is sent out through wire to `192.168.1.95`
5. `192.168.1.95` sends a response packet with `destination 100.64.0.77` and `source 192.168.1.95`
6. The response packet is only received on the `en0` interface
7. The response packet needs to be put onto the `utun` interface somehow so that my application can read the packet. How do I achieve this?

Some useful information below:

```
>netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.254      UGSc           en0       
default            link#10            UCSI         utun2       
100.64.0.77        100.64.0.77        UH           utun2       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1          link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1          link#10            UCSI         utun2       
192.168.1.92/32    link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1.99       8c:a9:82:2e:d6:2e  UHLWI          en0    986
192.168.1.254/32   link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1.254      70:f1:96:86:e6:a0  UHLWIir        en0   1196
224.0.0/4          link#7             UmCS           en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#10            UmCSI        utun2       
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#7             UCS            en0      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#10            UCSI         utun2   

>ifconfig utun2
flags=8051<up,POINTTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
options=6403<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
inet 100.64.0.77 --> 100.64.0.77 netmask 0xffffff00
```